# How to set parameter for dropdown list for the spinner in Android?

Tags: android, spinner

I have used `Spinner` in my `XML` file. It is working fine. When I click on the spinner, it shows a list of items for that spinner, but the size of `dropdown` list is so large which covers the whole screen. That's why it doesn't look good. So I want to know how I can set the width and height of the `dropdown` list so that it would look better.

Comment: have u got the answer of ur  question..i am also searching for same..pls help if u got it..

Comment: @Shyam No still i have not got the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea to solve your problem directly,but you can do these steps:

1. Create a layout(for example LinearLayout) that **seems look like spinner widget**(before user click on spinner).
2. Create an activity  with theme semitransparent or dialog and put a layout that is look like list for selecting spinner items and user sees it when clicked on spinner.
3. Add your quasi spinner layout to your UI.
4. Register a Click-listener for your quasi spinner,so that when user clicks on it,sees activity that contains list for selecting(start this activity for result,when user clicks your quasi spinner).